# File output to variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone help file output to variable

Below is the file output:

```
SAN Image:
Type: Primary
VHBA: A
SAN Image Path:
Type: Primary
LUN: 0
WWN: 20:00:
Type: Secondary
LUN: 10
WWN: 20:00:
Type: Secondary
VHBA: B
SAN Image Path:
Type: Primary
LUN: 20
WWN: 30:00:
Type: Secondary
LUN: 20
WWN: 30:00:
```

In above file we have multiple "Type: Primary".

I have used below code to assign variables:

```
search = "Type: Primary"
with open("file") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if search == line:
            vhba, ignore1, ignore2, lun1, wwn1, ignore3, lun2, wwn2 = islice(fin, 8)
            print vhba
            print wwn2
            break
```

I am expecting below variables has to get below values:

```
vhba =  A
lun1 = 10
wwn1 = 20:00:
wwn2 = 20:00:
```

(Basically these values i get from first 10 lines of the output)

Please help me how to get these values

Comment: `line` will have a newline character at the end `'\n'`, so `'Type: Primary'` will not match. Use `line = line.rstrip()` or similar to get rid of whitespace at the end of the line. See [**`str.rstrip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
searchT = "Type: Primary"
count = 0
with open('file') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line == searchT:
            count += 1
        if count == 2:
            count = 0

        if count <= 2:

            if line.split(" ")[0] == "VHBA:":
                vhba = line.split(" ")[1]
                print 'VHBA:'+vhba

            if line.split(" ")[0] == "LUN:":
                lun = line.split(" ")[1]
                print 'LUN:'+lun

            if line.split(" ")[0] == "WWN:":
                wwn = line.split(" ")[1]
                print 'WNN:'+wwn
```

Here I have just used a simple counter to read only the 'n' lines after keyword 'primary' and resetting it after 'n' lines to get the values.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the input that you have given in the question @PeterWood